# Ignore a folder containing a specific file in git

Tags: git, gitignore

In my root directory, there are several folders containing Python code. Sometimes, I may have to write ad hoc code for plotting some results quickly. But I do not want these files or the results on the remote repository. I can add such folders to `.gitignore` to exempt them from being added. Or I can unstage those folders after adding them. But I am looking for an easier way to do this.

I was thinking along the lines of `.nomedia` files. Media files in folders with a `.nomedia` file are ignored. Similarly, can I place some custom hidden file (say, `.nogit` or so) in the sub-directories which I do not want to include in git? Or is this not a healthy thing to do?

Comment: You can have multiple `.gitignore` files in a repo, each at a different level. Could be a better way than trying to reinvent the built-in feature.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I added a ```.gitignore``` in that sub-directory with ```*``` and the folder is now excluded.

Comment: (Additionnally and as a debug tool, note that you can do `git check-ignore -v path/to/file` and git will tell you if the file is ignored but also which `.gitignore` file is the cause)